# Access and remove negative pixels

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, signal-processing

How should I approach the problem of removing negative pixels from MRI slices (or any image)?

Also, it would really help if someone can briefly explain why they occur.

I have read many online references especially those on MATLAB forum, but they seem to have diverse reasons as to why they occur.

Sorry, I don't have a code to post, since I am figuring out my approach yet.

Answer (score 0):

An MRI slice is presumably for us here nothing but an image, which is also nothing but a matrix. Since a matrix representing an image have only positive values, 'a negative pixel' also, presumably, mean the pixels having a value lower than a certain threshold. Let's have such a scenario:
`load clown` loads a matrix `X` to your workspace representing a clown image, to see it first do `imagesc(X);colormap(gray);`. If you want to cut out some values lower than a threshold, you can do:

```
threshold=10;
newValue=0; 
X(find(X>threshold))=newValue;
imagesc(X)
colormap(gray)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume for example the following image matrix:

```
>> Img = [-2, -1, 0, 1, 2];
```

You could set all negative elements to zero:

```
>> ImgZeros = Img; 
>> ImgZeros(Img<0) = 0
ImgZeros =
 0     0     0     1     2
```

Or any other value useful to you, e.g. `NaN`:

```
>> ImgNans = Img;
>> ImgNans(Img<0) = nan 
ImgNans =
   NaN   NaN     0     1     2
```

You could 'shift' all the values up such that the lowest negative value becomes zero:

```
>> ImgZeroFloor = Img - min(Img(:))
ImgZeroFloor =
     0     1     2     3     4
```

You could convert the whole thing to a grayscale image in the range (0,1):

```
>> ImgGray = mat2gray(Img)
ImgGray =
     0    0.2500    0.5000    0.7500    1.0000
```

etc.

As to why you're getting negative values, who knows. It's problem specific. (If I had to guess for MRI I would say it's due to numerical inaccuracy during the conversion process from an MRI signal to pixel intensities.)

Answer (score 0):

Another way to limit your values is to use a sigmoid function

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function

It can be scaled so that all answers range from 0 to 255 
And it can be used to limit the spikes in raw data balance.
Its often used in neural networks.